# If I use a game from a family shared library then buy it, do my stats transfer?

Tags: steam-family-sharing

Now that Steam Family Sharing came out publicly, my brother and I share libraries. If I were to buy a game I've played through family sharing, would my stats (time played, achievements, saves, etc) transfer or would I have to start over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your stats, achievements and saves will carry over.